# How do I install the wise-Tiger WT-AC9006 driver?

Tags: 16.04, drivers, wireless

I want to install the driver for the wise-tiger external wifi adapter (model: WT-AC9006).  However, when I try to follow the steps available in the read-me file (available on-line on [their website here](http://www.wise-tiger.com/English/html/865412507.html)), I  get completely lost.

Could someone hold a newbie's hand and help me out with this one.  Merci!! :)

After running lsusb

```
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 0bda:0129 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTS5129 Card Reader Controller
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0a5c:21d7 Broadcom Corp. BCM43142 Bluetooth 4.0
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0bda:5756 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 8087:8001 Intel Corp. 
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0bda:0811 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. 
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

Comment: I doubt that this circa-2011 driver will compile on any recent Ubuntu version. Let's  see if there isn't a better way. Please insert the device and run the terminal command: `lsusb`. Next, edit your question to add the result.

Comment: Done...hope that helps :)

Comment: Please not that, in the duplicate, you have the exact same 0bda:0811 device. Don't you have an internal Broadcom wireless? Why do you need this USB?

Comment: Oh, I wanted to boost the range (also once it worked I was going to use it on my desktop which has not Broadcom driver).

Comment: I see. Follow the steps I enumerate in the duplicate and I'm confident you'll be up and running soon.

Comment: If you put this as an answer....I'll give you a ton of points...even if its a duplicate... it really helps me a ton!

Comment: I can't post an answer to a closed (duplicate) question. Simply follow the steps and upvote at the duplicate. Thanks.